# Plotting surface of a sphere using 3d Delaunay triangulated panels in R

Tags: r, 3d, plot, delaunay

[**EDIT**: more general solutions can be seen in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22630226/1199289)]

I'm wondering if anyone can help me plot an approximation of the surface of a sphere using XYZ coordinates. I have tried calculating Delaunay triangulated panels using the package `geometry` and then to plot iwith `rgl`. The first attempt, which looks nice, unfortunately created Delaunay 3d triangles that cross through the sphere. I would ultimately like to only plot the surface:

#### Generate 3d xyz data of a sphere

```
n <- 10 
rho <- 1
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi,, n) # azimuthal coordinate running from 0 to 2*pi 
phi <- seq(0, pi,, n) # polar coordinate running from 0 to pi (colatitude)
grd <- expand.grid(theta=theta, phi=phi)

x <- rho * cos(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
y <- rho * sin(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
z <- rho * cos(grd$phi)
xyzw <- cbind(x,y,z,w=1)
```

#### Calculate 3d Delaunay triangles and plot with rgl:

```
#install.packages("geometry")
library(geometry)
library(rgl)

tc <- delaunayn(xyzw[,1:3])
open3d()
tetramesh(tc,cbind(x,y,z), alpha=0.2, col=5)
rgl.snapshot("3d_delaunay.png")
```

[image]

#### Attempt at only returning surface triangles via 2d Delaunay triangulation

```
tc <- delaunayn(xyzw[,c(1:2)])
open3d()
for(i in seq(nrow(tc))){
    vertices <- c(t(xyzw[tc[i,],]))
    indices <- c( 1, 2, 3)
    shade3d( tmesh3d(vertices,indices) , alpha=0.2, col="cyan")
}
rgl.snapshot("2d_delaunay.png")
```

[image]

Obviously, something is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the convex hull, not the Delaunay triangulation. Here is a way with the **cxhull** package, but you can also use the **geometry** package.

```
library(tessellation)

n <- 10
rho <- 1
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = n) # azimuthal coordinate running from 0 to 2*pi
phi <- seq(0, pi, length.out = n) # polar coordinate running from 0 to pi (colatitude)
grd <- expand.grid(theta=theta, phi=phi)

x <- rho * cos(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
y <- rho * sin(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
z <- rho * cos(grd$phi)
xyz <- cbind(x,y,z)


library(cxhull)
hull <- cxhull(xyz, triangulate = TRUE)

library(rgl)
open3d()
for(facet in hull$facets){
  triangles3d(xyz[facet[["vertices"]], ], color = "green")
}
```

[image]