# 3d surface plot with xyz coordinates

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl, qhull

I am hoping someone with experience can help in how one prepares the shape files from xyz data. A great example of a well-prepared dataset can be seen [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/12/explore-a-comet-with-rs-rgl-package.html) for the comet Churyumov–Gerasimenko, although the preceding steps in creating the [shape file](http://sci.esa.int/rosetta/54728-shape-model-of-comet-67p/) are not provided.

I'm trying to better understand how to apply a surface to a given set of XYZ coordinates. Using Cartesian coordinates is straight forward with the R package "rgl", however shapes that wrap around seem more difficult. I found the R package `geometry`, which provides an interface to [QHULL](http://www.qhull.org/) functions. I tried using this to calculate Delaunay triangulated facets, which I can then plot in `rgl`. I'm unable to figure out some of the options associated with the function `delaunayn` to possibly control the maximum distances that these facets are calculated. I am hoping that someone here might have some ideas on improving the surface construction from xyz data.

#### Example using "Stanford bunnny" dataset:

```
library(onion)
library(rgl)
library(geometry)
data(bunny)

#XYZ point plot
open3d()
points3d(bunny, col=8, size=0.1)
#rgl.snapshot("3d_bunny_points.png")

#Facets following Delaunay triangulation
tc.bunny <- delaunayn(bunny)
open3d()
tetramesh(tc.bunny, bunny, alpha=0.25, col=8)
#rgl.snapshot("3d_bunny_facets.png")
```

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653763/1199289) makes me believe that there might be a problem with the R implementation of Qhull. Also, I have now tried various settings (e.g. `delaunayn(bunny, options="Qt")`) with little effect. Qhull options are outlined [here](http://www.qhull.org/html/qhull.htm)

#### Edit:

Here is an additional (simpler) example of a sphere. Even here, the calculation of facets does not always find the closest neighboring vertices (if you rotate the ball you will see some facets crossing through the interior).

```
library(rgl)
library(geometry)
set.seed(1)
n <- 10
rho <- 1
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi,, n) # azimuthal coordinate running from 0 to 2*pi 
phi <- seq(0, pi,, n) # polar coordinate running from 0 to pi (colatitude)
grd <- expand.grid(theta=theta, phi=phi)

x <- rho * cos(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
y <- rho * sin(grd$theta) * sin(grd$phi)
z <- rho * cos(grd$phi)

set.seed(1)
xyz <- cbind(x,y,z)
tbr = t(surf.tri(xyz, delaunayn(xyz)))
open3d()
rgl.triangles(xyz[tbr,1], xyz[tbr,2], xyz[tbr,3], col = 5, alpha=0.5)
rgl.snapshot("ball.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `alphashape3d` package?  I don't know that it's exactly what you're looking for, but you can get a nicer plot trying this:  `ashp <- ashape3d(bunny, alpha = c(0.005)); plot(ashp, col=c(8,8,8))`

Comment: @Frank - Thanks for the suggestion, but this example seems to have the same issue  - e.g. change `alpha = 0.5`.

Comment: There's no problem with the R implementation of Qhull in the `geometry` package: the Delaunay triangulation of a cloud of points is always the same as the Delaunay triangulation of the convex hull of this cloud of points. So your "delaunayised" bunny is convex.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an approach using kernel density estimation and the `contour3d` function from `misc3d`.  I played around until I found a value for `levels` that worked decently.  It's not perfectly precise, but you may be able to tweak things to get a better, more accurate surface.  If you have more than 8GB of memory, then you may be able to increase `n` beyond what I did here.

```
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)
library(onion); data(bunny)

# the larger the n, the longer it takes, the more RAM you need
bunny.dens <- kde3d(bunny[,1],bunny[,2],bunny[,3], n=150, 
    lims=c(-.1,.2,-.1,.2,-.1,.2)) # I chose lim values manually

contour3d(bunny.dens$d, level = 600, 
    color = "pink", color2 = "green", smooth=500)
rgl.viewpoint(zoom=.75)
```

[image][image]

The image on the right is from the bottom, just to show another view.

You can use a larger value for `n` in `kde3d` but it will take longer, and you may run out of RAM if the array becomes too large.  You could also try a different bandwidth (default used here). I took this approach from [Computing and Displaying Isosurfaces in R - Feng & Tierney 2008](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i01/paper).

---

Very similar isosurface approach using the `Rvcg` package:

```
library(Rvcg)
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)
library(onion); data(bunny)

bunny.dens <- kde3d(bunny[,1],bunny[,2],bunny[,3], n=150, 
    lims=c(-.1,.2,-.1,.2,-.1,.2)) # I chose lim values manually

bunny.mesh <- vcgIsosurface(bunny.dens$d, threshold=600)
shade3d(vcgSmooth(bunny.mesh,"HC",iteration=3),col="pink") # do a little smoothing
```

[image]

Since it's a density estimation based approach, we can get a little more out of it by increasing the density of the bunny.  I also use `n=400` here.  The cost is a significant increase in computation time, but the resulting surface is a *hare* better:

```
bunny.dens <- kde3d(rep(bunny[,1], 10), # increase density.
                    rep(bunny[,2], 10),
                    rep(bunny[,3], 10), n=400, 
                    lims=c(-.1,.2,-.1,.2,-.1,.2))

bunny.mesh <- vcgIsosurface(bunny.dens$d, threshold=600)
shade3d(vcgSmooth(bunny.mesh,"HC",iteration=1), col="pink")
```

[image]

---

Better, more efficient surface reconstruction methods exist (e.g. power crust, Poisson surface reconstruction, ball-pivot algorithm), but I don't know that any have been implemented in R, yet.

Here's a relevant Stack Overflow post with some great information and links to check out (including links to code):  [robust algorithm for surface reconstruction from 3D point cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud).

Comment: Great reference from Feng and Tierney (2008) - just what I've been looking for. I think this will give me a good start into finding related literature on the subject. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for your effort here Frank - you brought me a lot further with this topic. I like your rendition of a Silly Putty Bunny!

Answer (score 13):

I think have found one possible solution using the `alphashape3d` package. I had to play around a bit to get an acceptable value for `alpha`, which is related to the distances in the given data set (e.g. `sd` of `bunny` gave me some insight). I'm still trying to figure out how to better control the width of lines in vertices and edges so as not to dominate the plot, but this is probably related to settings in `rgl`.

#### Example:

```
library(onion)
library(rgl)
library(geometry)
library(alphashape3d)

data(bunny)
apply(bunny,2,sd)
alphabunny <- ashape3d(bunny, alpha = 0.003)
bg3d(1)
plot.ashape3d(alphabunny, col=c(5,5,5), lwd=0.001, size=0, transparency=rep(0.5,3), indexAlpha = "all")
```

[image]

#### Edit:

Only by adjusting the `plot.ashape3d` function, was I able to remove the edges and vertices:

```
plot.ashape3d.2 <- function (x, clear = TRUE, col = c(2, 2, 2), byComponents = FALSE, 
                             indexAlpha = 1, transparency = 1, walpha = FALSE, ...) 
{
  as3d <- x
  triangles <- as3d$triang
  edges <- as3d$edge
  vertex <- as3d$vertex
  x <- as3d$x
  if (class(indexAlpha) == "character") 
    if (indexAlpha == "ALL" | indexAlpha == "all") 
      indexAlpha = 1:length(as3d$alpha)
  if (any(indexAlpha > length(as3d$alpha)) | any(indexAlpha <= 
                                                   0)) {
    if (max(indexAlpha) > length(as3d$alpha)) 
      error = max(indexAlpha)
    else error = min(indexAlpha)
    stop(paste("indexAlpha out of bound : valid range = 1:", 
               length(as3d$alpha), ", problematic value = ", error, 
               sep = ""), call. = TRUE)
  }
  if (clear) {
    rgl.clear()
  }
  if (byComponents) {
    components = components_ashape3d(as3d, indexAlpha)
    if (length(indexAlpha) == 1) 
      components = list(components)
    indexComponents = 0
    for (iAlpha in indexAlpha) {
      if (iAlpha != indexAlpha[1]) 
        rgl.open()
      if (walpha) 
        title3d(main = paste("alpha =", as3d$alpha[iAlpha]))
      cat("Device ", rgl.cur(), " : alpha = ", as3d$alpha[iAlpha], 
          "\n")
      indexComponents = indexComponents + 1
      components[[indexComponents]][components[[indexComponents]] == 
                                      -1] = 0
      colors = c("#000000", sample(rainbow(max(components[[indexComponents]]))))
      tr <- t(triangles[triangles[, 8 + iAlpha] == 2 | 
                          triangles[, 8 + iAlpha] == 3, c("tr1", "tr2", 
                                                          "tr3")])
      if (length(tr) != 0) 
        rgl.triangles(x[tr, 1], x[tr, 2], x[tr, 3], col = colors[1 + 
                                                                   components[[indexComponents]][tr]], alpha = transparency, 
                      ...)
    }
  }
  else {
    for (iAlpha in indexAlpha) {
      if (iAlpha != indexAlpha[1]) 
        rgl.open()
      if (walpha) 
        title3d(main = paste("alpha =", as3d$alpha[iAlpha]))
      cat("Device ", rgl.cur(), " : alpha = ", as3d$alpha[iAlpha], 
          "\n")
      tr <- t(triangles[triangles[, 8 + iAlpha] == 2 | 
                          triangles[, 8 + iAlpha] == 3, c("tr1", "tr2", 
                                                          "tr3")])
      if (length(tr) != 0) 
        rgl.triangles(x[tr, 1], x[tr, 2], x[tr, 3], col = col[1], 
                      , alpha = transparency, ...)
    }
  }
}

alphabunny <- ashape3d(bunny, alpha = c(0.003))
plot.ashape3d.2(alphabunny, col=5, indexAlpha = "all", transparency=1)
bg3d(1)
```

[image]

Comment: So, my answer did work for you!  I didn't post it as an answer because I wasn't sure it was what you needed.  Anyway, you only need to use `indexAlpha = "all"` if you used more than one `alpha` value in your call to `ashape3d` and you want to plot the results for all the `alpha` values you tried.

Comment: @Frank - I honestly didn't realize that this was the same package that you recommended! I came across it through another Google search and the package's vignette helped me figure the settings out. I'll try your recommendations out. Cheers!

Comment: @Frank - Looks like I confused `alpha` with `transparency`. You should write a formal answer here.

Comment: That second plot with your adjusted `plot.ashape3d.2` is pretty cool!  I found that `alpha = 0.0015` makes for a pretty nice image.

Comment: @Frank - Yes, `alpha = 0.0015` gives a better result in some places, but there's holes all over if you look closely.

Answer (score 3):

The package `Rvcg` updated to version 0.14 in July 2016, and ball pivoting surface reconstruction was added. The function is `vcgBallPivoting`:

```
library(Rvcg) # needs to be >= version 0.14
library(rgl)
library(onion); data(bunny)

# default parameters
bunnybp <- vcgBallPivoting(bunny, radius = 0.0022, clustering = 0.2, angle = pi/2)
shade3d(bunnybp, col = rainbow(1000), specular = "black")
shade3d(bunnybp, col = "pink", specular = "black") # easier to see problem areas.
```

[image]
[image]

The ball pivoting and the default parameter settings are not perfect for the Stanford bunny (as noted by cuttlefish44 in the comments `radius = 0.0022` does better than the default `radius = 0`), and you are left with some gaps in the surface.  The actual bunny has 2 holes in the base and some scanning limitations contribute to a few other holes (as mentioned here: https://graphics.stanford.edu/software/scanview/models/bunny.html).  You may be able to find better parameters, and it's quite fast to use `vcgBallPivoting` (~0.5 seconds on my machine), but additional effort / methods may be required to close the gaps.

Comment: This is really fast - thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get rid of those holes by playing around with the argument parameters. BTW, the vcgBallPivoting function crashes R when using RStudio. I've notified the package authors.

Comment: Your answer is so interesting for me. `radius = 0.0022` returns better output, but not perfect...

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently making a package, [RCGAL](https://github.com/stla/RCGAL), which currently offers two types of surface reconstruction. It is based on the [RcppCGAL](https://github.com/ericdunipace/RcppCGAL/) package, which links to the header files of the C++ library CGAL (Computational Geometry Algorithms Library).

Here is the *advanced front surface reconstruction* of the Stanford bunny:

[image]

Here is the *Poisson surface reconstruction* of the Stanford bunny with the default parameters:

[image]

This mesh is not very precise. One gets a more precise mesh by using a smaller value of the `spacing` parameter:

[image]

See [this blog post](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/SurfaceReconstruction.html) for more info.

Comment: This looks very nice. Perhaps you should provide code for your answer so that others may reproduce.

Comment: @Marcinthebox added link to my blog