# how to plot non-convex surface from set of n x 3 data

Tags: r, delaunay, qhull

Is there a straight forward way to plot a non-convex surface in R?

I have used something like the following for convex surfaces and it works fine:

```
xyz <- cbind(y,x,z)
tbr <- t(surf.tri(xyz, delaunayn(xyz)))
rgl.triangles(xyz[tbr,1], xyz[tbr,2], xyz[tbr,3])
```

However, for non-convex surfaces, concave areas become filled. I think this is a problem with the function `delaunayn()` as it uses the *Qhull* library which does not support *constrained Delaunay* triangulations or mesh generation of non-convex objects.

Any suggestions appreciated.

P.S.

I have data as an ascii file but it has 3 columns and is 225 lines long. What is the best way of providing this?

Data available at: http://pastebin.com/R2p4Cf7d

The top of the plot should be concave! This is an image created using `persp3d()` of how the surface should look. It has been calculated using more grid points on a regular grid in polar coordinates, rather than using irregular collocation points.

[image: Correct rendering of surface, but with more grid points.]

Comment: Please add a reproducable example, something with simulated data.

Comment: A Delaunay triangulation is always convex. Maybe you need to modify plot colours for some boundary triangles (i.e. those with a long edge)

Comment: Check out the alphahull package.

Comment: What happens if you just munge your `x,y,z` data a bit and use `lattice::wireframe` with shading or draping?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel `deldir::deldir()` does something better than `geometry::delaunayn()` in this case (as a memorial to a new function `rgl::plot3d.deldir()`). (I used [OP's Data](http://pastebin.com/R2p4Cf7d).)

```
library(rgl); library(deldir)

dxyz <- deldir(xyz[,1], xyz[,2], z=xyz[,3])

open3d()
plot3d(dxyz, col=cm.colors(256)[cut(xyz[,3], 256)], alpha=0.9)  # there isn't a bottom
wire3d(as.mesh3d(dxyz), col="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example. However, using the same data (skipping header) plot3d() throws an error. I have tried different data formats to no avail. How did you read in the data?

Comment: Just updated packages deldir and rgl and code works fine. Thanks again, this is great.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution is not perfect, but works if you have a copy of Matlab.

```
library(rgl)
library(geometry)
# Read in data - also at: http://pastebin.com/R2p4Cf7d
simDat <- read.csv("testDat.csv")
#
x   <- simDat[,1];y<-simDat[,2];z<-simDat[,3]
xyz <- cbind(simDat[,1],simDat[,2],simDat[,3])
#
triNodes <- delaunayn(xyz)
tbr1     <- t(surf.tri(xyz, triNodes ))
# Plot data from R generated triangles
open3d()
rgl.triangles(xyz[tbr1,1], xyz[tbr1,2], xyz[tbr1,3])
#
# Import data generated by Matlab function delaunay()
#  - also at: http://pastebin.com/vQV2Zaii
nodeDat_ML <- read.csv("testDatNodes.csv")
triNodes2  <- cbind(nodeDat_ML[,1], nodeDat_ML[,2], nodeDat_ML[,3],1)
#
tbr2 <- t(surf.tri(xyz, triNodes2))
# Plot data from Matlab generated triangles
open3d()
rgl.triangles(xyz[tbr2,1], xyz[tbr2,2], xyz[tbr2,3])
```

The code produces the following two surfaces. The left plot is based on triangulation generated by the R function delaunayn(), and the right plot is based on triangulation generated from the Matlab function delaunay().

[image: Plots from R and Matlab generated triangulations]

The Matlab generated data is available at: http://pastebin.com/vQV2Zaii

and the associated Matblab code is:

```
fname = 'testDat.csv';
tt = table2array(readtable(fname)); % get data
x =  tt(:,1);y = tt(:,2);z = tt(:,3);
tri = delaunay(x,y); % the triangulation data
trisurf(tri,x(:,1),y(:,1),z(:,1)); % surface plot
```

The result is not entirely perfect as the final plot (right) has a spurious triangle.

I hope the above will be useful to anyone with a similar problem.