# surface plots of large 3D datasets using R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, delaunay

Although this post may be related previous ones (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607406/plotting-surface-of-a-sphere-using-3d-delaunay-triangulated-panels-in-r)), it also involves a larger dataset (i.e., numbers of points ~1e5), which describes the surface of a 3D object (think of a single particle in high definition), defined by regularly-spaced (x,y,z) value forming a closed volume. These points only describe the surface; the interior space is empty. I want to plot this surface using R. My first attempt used plot3d in rgl:

```
library(rgl)
d=read.table("./sample_particle.txt", col.names=c("x","y","z")) 
x=d$x
y=d$y
z=d$z
p <- plot3d(x,y,z,colrvar=z,col=gray(seq(0.1,1,length=5)))
```

With this result
[image: plot3d result]

I now want to plot the surface of this object (and not simply the discrete points), but need some guidance as to how to accomplish this. The particle shape varies between a rough cube and sphere, and thus a given x, y coordinate will occur twice: does this make construction of Delaunay triangles impossible? If not, can anyone suggest a routine that can deal with larger datasets?

Comment: It will probably help potential answerers if you post or link to an excerpt of the data

Comment: That's a **lot** of points to generate a mesh/surface for! You may want to consider subsampling; the resultant plot will not suffer significantly.  Now, there are tools in (I believe) the `plot3d` or `misc3d` packages which will convert your x,y,z location data to matrices compatible with functions such as `surface3d` or `lattice:wiregrid` . That may be a better way to go.

Comment: @Carl, thanks very much for this response and pointer -- I will look in these packages ... Cheers //rolf